# Chaining function applications in python

Tags: python, function

Is there a shortcut in python for applying the same function `multiple times` to a variable (and its output)?

Something like:

```
# n times foo(x)
```

instead of

```
foo(foo(foo...(foo(x))))...)
```

Comment: A `for` loop is best for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in range(n):
    x = foo(x)
```

If you need to preserve x, use a different name

```
baz = x
for i in range(n):
    baz = foo(baz)
```

If you are desperate for a shortcut (eg. for codegolf)

```
reduce(lambda x,y:foo(x),[x]*n)
```

Comment: the shortcut is too smart.

Answer (score 3):

```py
def double(x):
    return x * 2

i = 44
for i in xrange(1,100):
    i = double(i)
```

Could you mean a simple for loop?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways i can think of is creating a generic recursive function to do this

```
def repeatX(foo, output, count):
      if not count:
         return output
      else:
         return repeatX(foo, foo(output), count -1)
```

Comment: Unchecked recursion in python is pretty much always a bad idea.